# GTK3: Get mouse scroll direction

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I just ported a C program from GTK2 to GTK3. The program uses a `GtkDrawingArea` on which the mouse scroll wheel is used. After the switch to GTK3 I am not able to detect the scroll wheel usage properly anymore. Here is what I do and get:

**GTK2 (2.24.10)**

1. I set the event mask of the `GtkDrawingArea` to `GDK_EXPOSURE_MASK | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK | GDK_LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK`.
2. I connect a signal handler to `scroll-event` of the `GtkDrawingArea`.
3. Once I use the scroll wheel, the signal handler is called and the property `direction` of the `GdkEventScroll` is either `GDK_SCROLL_UP` or `GDK_SCROLL_DOWN`.

**GTK3 (3.4.2)**

1. In addition to the above, I include `GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK` in the event mask of the `GtkDrawingArea`. Without that, my signal handler is never called.
2. I use the same signal handler as described above.
3. Once I use the scroll wheel, the signal handler is called and the property `direction` of the `GdkEventScroll` is `GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH`. Calling `gdk_event_get_scroll_deltas()` gives me always 0 for both `delta_x` and `delta_y`. I never see any other directions than  `GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH`.

I can live with receiving smooth scroll events although my mouse itself only delivers "discrete" button4/5 events, but how do I figure out the direction of the scroll event?

BTW: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on amd64.

Comment: I found a [discussion about the switch from `GDK_SCROLL_{UP|DOWN}` to `GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH`](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.desktop/46513) but the problem with delta_x and delta_y being 0 is not mentioned there.

Comment: Did you try adding GDK_SCROLL_MASK? Assuming you don't care about smooth scrolling that is.  See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671305

Comment: @ergosys: Yes, I included `GDK_SCROLL_MASK` (see 1. under GTK3). Without this flag my signal handler is never called under GTK3.

Comment: I don't see where you do.  You have GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK, which is a different mask.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the constant name from your reply. I added `GDK_SCROLL_MASK` but it does not make any difference. I still only get `GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH` events.

Comment: @ergosys: `GDK_SCROLL_MASK` turned out to be a good tip! When I set `GDK_SCROLL_MASK` and omit `GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK` my app gets the "discrete" `GDK_SCROLL_UP`and `GDK_SCROLL_DOWN` events again! Also, I don't get any `GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH` events. While this solution does not explain why smooth scrolling does not work as expected, it solves my original problem. I currently don't use an input device that allows smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675959) in Gtk3 associated with the "scroll-event" signal. First, in your callback you should use the delta_x and delta_y members of the GdkEventScroll structure. Second, the first time you scroll your mouse, these members will both be zero (bug!). Subsequent scrolls will give you correct values. Third, it seems this bug will not be fixed, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However, in my tests delta_x and delta_y were always 0, not only for the first event. Anyway, I gave up finding the source of the problem and switched to GDK_SCROLL_UP/DOWN instead of GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on gnome 3.38 (X11 based) using the newest stable GTK4 build (as of aug 2022) and to this day, if `GDK_SCROLL_MASK` is enabled, all `GdkScrollEvents` will have a delta of 0 (at all times, not just the first), so it just doesn't work at all I guess.

The alternative was to instead enable `GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK`, connect to the `"scroll-event"` signal using the same signature as with `GDK_SCROLL_MASK`, then access the delta like so:

```cpp
gboolean on_scroll_event(GtkWidget*, GdkEventScroll* event, gpointer*)
{
    // ignore all events fitting GDK_SCROLL_MASK
    if (event->type != GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH)
        return false;

    double delta_x, delta_y;
    gdk_event_get_scroll_deltas((GdkEvent*) event, &x, &y);

    // use delta_x and delta_y here
    // do NOT use event->delta_x / event->delta_y
}
```

Note that I don't see a reason to ever enable `GDK_SCROLL_MASK` at all, if you don't enable it the if branch above is unnecessary.